# How to display progressbar 0 to value

Tags: javafx, progress-bar

i want to show result 80 percent when i got result.(start 0 to myresult=80)

but my progressbar is show result 0 until 100 (max of procress bar)

```
 @FXML
private ProgressBar progress;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    double percent = 0.8;
    progress.setProgress(percent);
    progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.start();

    // TODOs
}
public Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(i + 1);
            updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

thank you for comment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not quite clear what you are asking - can you edit your question to clarify what it is that you are trying to achieve, and what the actual result is? If you can produce images/screenshot to demonstrate your issue it might also help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to the `progress` property of the task, bind to the `progress` property multiplied by `0.8`. This way you convert the `[0, 1]` range of the task progress to range `[0, 0.8]`:

```
progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty().multiply(0.8));
```